# Restar -30 dias para atras en una consulta oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

una manera de generar una consulta que me reste 30 dias   y que me traiga todos los  registros que tienen fechas menor a 30 dias

```
select
mcestcred, mcfinanc, fhfinanc, mcimpago, mcdemora, 
to_char(fhcobro,'dd-mm-yy')as fhcobro 
from tsffacturc 
where fhcobro= sysdate-30;
```

Generé esta pero al parecer no me entrega ningun valor aun existiendo fechas mucho mas antiguas  ya que al parecer le digo a la consulta solo los datos con fecha -30 dias  y yo quiero q me traiga todos las fechas que se pasaron por 30 dias
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes. ¿Tendrás unos datos de ejemplo en la tabla que estás consultando, como para poder probar tu consulta? Por favor [edit] tu pregunta y añade esta información.

Comment: el problema es fhcobro= sysdate-30 entonces solo traes fhcobro que sea exactamente igual a hace 30 dias... vos lo que queres ahi es un mayor ;)

Comment: si es el detalle yo quiero hacer una regresion a todos los datos -a 30 dias  usando la fila fhcobro

Comment: Leé de nuevo, ya te indicaron qué hacer: _vos lo que querés ahí es un mayor_.